# TimeSeparator differs between on-prem server and Azure Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, datetime-format, culture

I'm about to move a legacy system from a 3rd party hosting provider to Azure web apps.

These are the characteristics of the system:

- Asp.Net Mvc (some razor views but mostly REST-api's)
- Angular 1x
- Dotnet Framework 4.7.1 (yes, we've upgraded to a more recent version of DNF)

During testing I found a bug on the client when moment.js is trying to parse a dateTime returned by the REST api.

After some research it seems that Azure returnes datetimes with a "." (dot) as the timeseparator, i.e. "12.10.22". 
However, the hosted solution returns ":" (colon) as the timeseparator, i.e. "12:10:22", even though *Culture* are set to *nb-NO* and *uiCultire* are set to *nb-NO* in web.config:

```
 <globalization culture="nb-NO" uiCulture="nb" />
```

I'm hesitant about changing the culture to *en-US* to force the system to use colon as the timeseparator, as I don't know if this will introduce other bugs.

Anyone knows why this happens, and have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Regards,
Jon

Answer (score 1):

The [culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.100).aspx) specifies the default culture for processing incoming web requests.

**Default Configuration**

The following default globalization element is not explicitly configured in the Machine.config file or in the root Web.config file. However, it is the default configuration that is returned by application.

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" 
               responseEncoding="utf-8" 
               fileEncoding="" 
               culture="" 
               uiCulture="" 
               enableClientBasedCulture="false" 
               responseHeaderEncoding="utf-8" 
               resourceProviderFactoryType="" 
               enableBestFitResponseEncoding="false" />
```

The [invariant culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(vs.71).aspx) is culture-insensitive. **You can specify the invariant culture by name using an empty string ("") or by its culture identifier 0x007F.**

`InvariantCulture` retrieves an instance of the invariant culture. It is **associated with the English language but not with any country/region**. It can be used in almost any method in the Globalization namespace that requires a culture.

If a security decision depends on a string comparison or a case-change operation, use the InvariantCulture to ensure that the behavior will be consistent regardless of the culture settings of the system.

So, you could set `<globalization uiCulture="" culture="" />` in web.config or just not configure using the default configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the info and suggestion, but as I'm not sure why the culture-parameters was added to web.config in the first place I'd rather not change this setting.